# how to delay a execution?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

I am creating a small project such that after pressing a button which 
will take me to the next view controller using the navigation controller - can i delay the function to execute the navigation controller after some time

i am using this code-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   @IBAction func enterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
   {
       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
   {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

}
```

Comment: What is your questions?

Comment: You want to play audio after 5/10 sec or play with offset of 5/10 sec ? To schedule after 5/10sec use NSTimer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `sender.tag` holds the duration which is 0 for proceed , 5 or 10

```
var playTimer:Timer?
```

//

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {

    playTimer?.invalidate()

    playTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(sender.tag), repeats: false, block: { (T) in

        // play the audio

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var timeLimit = 5.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeLimit, execute: {
    //Play your audio here
    //Audio will play after 5 seconds here
})
```

Comment: Actually asyncAfter is not guaranteed to be called at a specific time, it is guaranteed to be run after specified time, not sure this is correct answer